# callback in node-schedule's callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduled-tasks, loopbackjs

In my (express.js based) loopback app I want to schedule a task to run every 1 second. It should count every open ticket, and if they already open for a certain time, then an email should be sent. Below is a simplified code.

The problem, that 'scheduleJob' is logged, as expected, but the number of tickets is not. I think it is a context problem. How should I log the number of the found ticket? How should I communicate back from `count` 's callback to the `schedule` 's callback?

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
module.exports = function(app) {
  var Ticket = app.models['Ticket']

  var j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', function(){
    console.log('scheduleJob')
    Ticket.count(function(err, count){
      if (err) {console.log(err)}
      console.log(count)
    })
  });
};
```

Comment: Have you considered using Promises or async-await to control the flow of your Job function?  Have you considered using the much much simpler setInterval methodology for getting your Job to run on such a regular schedule (at least during development)?  Have you considered how running the Job every second will prevent your app from scaling up?

Comment: @O.Jones I have solved the problem with async-await. In production we plan a 1 minute schedule. I also feel that this scheduling is very resource heavy, but as I in a comment already wrote: The problem that I have to send an email if the ticket is open for a certain time (differs from ticket to ticket). Eg. if ticke1 is open for 30 minutes and ticket2 is open for 45 minutes an email has to be sent. ATM I don't see a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do not count all the open ticket like that - It costs a lots of resources.

You should keep the number of ticket in your node.js and increase/decrease it. If you have multiple processes interacting with the database, makes one of them your master and make it handle this task.

---

About your problem, it seems that the library `node-schedule` do not support asynchronous calls.

---

---

**Algorithm**

At your program start, look up at the ticket in your database and retrieve the next timestamp when you should send an email.

Example, you want to send an email if a ticket is open for 1 hour, and your database have :

```
ticket 1 / 10 min
ticket 2 / 40 min
```

So your next mail should be sent in 20 min (60 min - 40 min).

use `setTimeout()` to wake up your node in 20 min. When you wake up, send the mail, and look at your database again for the next mail to send.

Recalcul your `setTimeout` if there is a new Ticket inserted in your database or If one get removed/updated.

Comment: The problem that I have to send an email if the ticket is open for a certain time (differs from ticket to ticket). Eg. if ticke1 is open for 30 minutes and ticket2 is open for 45 minutes an email has to be sent. "About your problem, it seems that the library node-schedule do not support asynchronous calls." Do you have any suggestion how could I overcome this, or a different scheduling library?